# Bash autocomplete: first list files then cycle through them

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Is it possible to configure bash in such a way that on the first tab autocomplete it lists all possible files and on subsequent ones cycles through the choices?

Both options are easy to do separately and I could bind them to different keys, but the above would be perfect, but I can't find anything about it on the net.

Comment: It's been a while since I have used ZSH, but I believe its autocomplete functions like this.

Comment: @jordanm Well seems like an option if nothing else works, but that would also entail updating everything from .bashrc, etc. to the ZSH equivalents, which I'd quite like to avoid.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This seems close to what you want:

```
bind "TAB:menu-complete"
bind "set show-all-if-ambiguous on"
```

Comment: Almost perfect, apart from the small flaw that it also autocompletes on the first tab, which can be a bit annoying if I'm just trying to figure out the exact name (i.e. I have to delete quite a bit more characters if I want to change then), but I'm quite willing to live with that.

Comment: How can this easily be undone?

Comment: `bind "TAB:complete"; bind "set show-all-if-ambiguous off"`

Comment: @Voo add the third line `bind "set menu-complete-display-prefix on"` will just list the candidates on the first tab without auto-completion.

Comment: @Naitree can't upvote your suggestion enough. It works and IS so, so much better than the default bash behavior. Thank you.

Comment: It might be worth noting that both `→` and `ESC` work for going into the current folder and continuing cycling there.

Answer (score 22):

This is what I use. As far as I can tell it does exactly what you want.

```bsh
# make tab cycle through commands after listing
bind '"\t":menu-complete'
bind "set show-all-if-ambiguous on"
bind "set completion-ignore-case on"
bind "set menu-complete-display-prefix on"
```

This works on Mac (10.13 & 10.14) and Ubuntu (16.04 & 18.04).

Comment: This is seriously the best user experience I've ever had. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered? It was referenced at Superuser ...

```
[[ $- = *i* ]] && bind TAB:menu-complete
```

Comment: `menu-complete` is only half of what the question is asking.  As the question says, *"[b]oth options are easy to do separately"*.

Comment: Yes I know how to change the behavior to one of the two options, but that's the easy part. The real problem is how to combine the two into one.

Comment: Can you explain to me the detail of what's going on in that line?